# The user can only see their own profile

Tags: php

I would like it if I'm logged in as an administrator can look at the profiles of all users if they are logged in as a subscriber, for example, "toni123456" Can I see only your profile "toni123456". This is a template domain/wordpress/**author**/user_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your template you can implement a condition checking if the user is a super admin or if the user has certain capabilities (if you want to target administrators and not only super admins)

**First case**

```
if (is_super_admin() ) {
    //your super admin logic here
}else{
    //subscriber logic
}
```

**Second case**

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    //your admin logic here
} else {
    //subscriber logic
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_super_admin

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Also here you can use this function to check user roles

http://docs.appthemes.com/tutorials/wordpress-check-user-role-function/

**UPDATE**

An update according to op question

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        //your admin logic here
    } else {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));

        if($current_user->user_login == $curauth->user_login){
          // User is the same as author, show the panel
        }else{
          //different user and author, access forbidden.
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'Access forbidden';
}
```

Comment: it will be fine just like I would have if sm logged in as "toni123" that you can only see the profile of "toni123" So my profile but not from another user

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. With the code above you can check which type of user is logged in and act appropriate.

Comment: a list of username: 1: admin 2: toni123 3: miha123 

each user on wordpress has its own profile mysite/wordpress/author/username 

Example1 > So I would like if I sign up as an example, a user with the username "toni123" if I go to mysite/wordpress/author/toni123 do I see my profile page if you go to mysite/wordpress/author/miha123 it I can write that I do not have access because I'm not an administrator. 

Example2 > if I'm logged in as "miha123" is just the opposite. 

Example3 > If I'm logged in as an administrator, I have access to all users

Comment: therefore: 
I need to add some code here *** 

if (current_user_can ('manage_options')) {
     / / your logic here admin 
}else { 

     *** 
}

Comment: I made an update to my answer.